# Changing text size of Selected Cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to change the text size of collection view cell label and works a little bit. When I select item index wise(cell 0, cell 1, cell 2....) it works for me But when I try to select item on random index(like: cell 0 to cell 3) then my app crashes

I'm trying this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
    let idxPath = IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: 0)
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: idxPath)
    let myCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: idxPath) as! MenuCell
    cell?.isSelected = true
    myCell.isSelected = true
    myCell.title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: idxPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let idxPath = IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: 0)
    let myCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: idxPath) as! MenuCell
    myCell.isSelected = false
    myCell.title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
}
```

It's working in series cell selection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRtMH.png)

But when i select cell randomly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr46a.png)

**Thanks, and sorry for my bad english**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you recreate `IndexPath` and then making force unwrap for the cell.
If you have to change font just for first section, so try to change code like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
      let myCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MenuCell
       myCell?.isSelected = false
       myCell?.title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
    }
}
```

Comment: It kinda works for me but some cell text remains at size:16 after deselecting

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var selectedCell = [Int]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: yourCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MenuCell

    //Code for change font size

    if selectedCell.contains(indexPath.cell){
       cell.title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    }else{
       cell.title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
    if selectedCell.contains(indexPath.item){
       selectedCell.remove(at: selectedCell.index(of: selectedCell.contains[indexPath.item])!)
    }else{
       selectedCell.append(indexPath.item)
    }
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: It gives me error of 'Use of unresolved identifier 'selectedCell'

Comment: @FaisalShahzad you have to declare an integer array selectedCell 
i have edited the above code and added an integer array